# breeze - example of how to perform custom save

Tags: breeze

I have read this documentation on breeze about customizing saving calls from the client - http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/saving-changes - 
and what is describes sounds like exactly what I want to do -

> "But you might have a specific business process to perform when you
>   save a certain constellation of entities. Perhaps the actual storing
>   of changes in the database is only a part of a much larger server-side
>   workflow. What you really have is a "command" that includes a database
>   update."

I don't really see how to put this into practice though. Say I have entity "A" that when I save, needs to kick of some custom business processes. Well, I could split off entities of Type A on the client and do something like

```
var so = new SaveOptions({ resourceName: "myCustomSave" });
myEntityManager.savechanges(Aentities, so);  
myEntityManager.saveChanges(everythingButAEntities);
```

But then I'll just hit "myCustomSave" with a JObject "saveBundle".

Do I deserialize into entities, do my custom business processes, and then serialize back into a savebundle and send on to be saved?

And say entity A has a child Entity C - how do the relationships get updated if C is being saved through the standard getChanges?

I know I can [intercept the save request](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/efcontextprovider#SaveInterception) and override the BeforeSaveEntity method, but it kind of feels like putting my business logic in the data layer. This does seem like the easiest way to do it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the *BeforeSaveEntities* method. It takes a *saveMap* parameter that you can update with newly added/modified entities during the save process.

http://www.getbreezenow.com/breeze-sharp-documentation/contextprovider